# How to remove duplicate row in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter frame work and I am trying to stop duplicate record in my table
In my table record are repeat I want to show one record at one time

This is my code

Controller

```
  $modelResult = $this->freightBillModel->freightBillByDate($data);
  <table id="freight_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm" style="display:block; overflow: auto; ">
             <tr>
              <th>SR.No</th>
              <th>Bill No</th>
              <th>pkgs</th>
              <th>freight</th>
             </tr>
             <tbody>
                <?php  $counter = 1;   ?>
                <?php foreach($modelResult as $freight){?>

            <tr>

              <td><?php echo $counter;?></td>
              <td><?php echo $freight['tbb_no'];?></td>
              <?php $singleBill = $this->freightBillModel->fetchBillByNo($freight['tbb_no']);  ?>
              <?php $lr_freight=0; $no_of_pkgs=0; ?>

              <?php foreach ($singleBill as $bill) : ?>
              <?php $lr_freight+=$bill->lr_freight; ?>
              <?php $no_of_pkgs+=$bill->no_of_pkgs; ?>
              <?php endforeach; ?>

              <td><?php echo $no_of_pkgs;?></td>
              <td><?php echo $lr_freight;?></td>


             </tr>
            <?php  $counter++; ?>
            <?php }?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Model:

```
        public function freightBillByDate($data){
        extract($data);
        $this->db->select('bn.branch_name as to,ts_tbb.tbb_no,ts_tbb.tbb_id,ts_tbb.bilty_id,ts_tbb.current_time,ts_tbb.status,b.*');
        $this->db->from('ts_tbb');
        $this->db->join('bilty b', 'b.id = ts_tbb.bilty_id');

        $this->db->join('branch bn', 'b.lr_to=bn.branch_id');

        $this->db->where('lr_from',$lr_from);
        $this->db->where('lr_to',$lr_to);


        if($bill_type=="pending_bill"){

               $this->db->where('billed_status','not_billed');

         }else if($bill_type=="bill_register"){

               $this->db->where('billed_status','billed');
         }




        $this->db->order_by('lr_date','desc');


        $query=$this->db->get();
       return $query->result_array();

}
function fetchBillByNo($billNo){
    return $this->db->select('*')->from('ts_tbb')->join('bilty','bilty_id=bilty.id')->where('tbb_no',$billNo)->get()->result();
}[![In this picture first two records are repeat][1]][1]
```

I want to show unique records,
Current table it shows duplicate rows
Please tell me where i am wrong in my code

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use a SELECT DISTINCT instead of SELECT if you want to query the distinct rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `DISTINCT` keyword in your `select()`

```
return $this->db
->select('DISTINCT YOUR_ID_FIELD')
->select('*')
->from('ts_tbb')
->join('bilty','bilty_id=bilty.id')
->where('tbb_no',$billNo)
->get()
->result();
```

Or else, you can use `group by` like this:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->group_by('YOUR_ID_FIELD');
```

Comment: in first query I want to distinct by "ts_tbb.tbb_no" @pupil

Comment: $this->db->distinct(); how can use distinct for only one column @Rakesh Jakhar

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the duplicate records not a good practice, You can remove all the duplicated by SQL query.

For example :

```
DELETE t1 FROM contacts t1
INNER JOIN
contacts t2 
WHERE
t1.id < t2.id AND t1.email = t2.email;
```

Above SQL query will remove the duplicates email rows and keeps the highest id.